# Can't inheritance class in javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: Weather is not defined

Tags: javascript, class

**I got this error while running the code Uncaught ReferenceError: Climate is not defined.**
I'm making a weather app using API but my code cant inheritance class.

```
// Init weather object
const weather = new Weather('Boston', 'MA');

// Get weather on DOM load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);

// weather.changeLocation('Miami', 'FL');

function getWeather(){
  weather.getWeather()
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

class Weather {
    constructor(city, state) {
      this.apiKey = 'b4d8**';
      this.city = city;
      this.state = state;
    };
  
    // Fetch weather from API
    async getWeather() {
      const response = await fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.city}&${this.state}&appid=${this.apiKey}`);
  
      const responseData = await response.json();
  
      return responseData.current_observation;
    };
  
    // Change weather location
    changeLocation(city, state) {
      this.city = city;
      this.state = state;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` declarations work like `let` and `const`: You cannot access the binding (variable) until it was initialized.

Solution: Move the class declaration to the top.

Answer (score 0):

An important difference between function declarations and class declarations is that function declarations are hoisted and class declarations are not. You first need to declare your class and then access it, otherwise code like the following will throw a ReferenceError

const p = new Rectangle(); // ReferenceError

class Rectangle {}